# Crontab error when running Python script

Tags: python, cron, vertica

I have a crontab to run a Python script:

```
1 3 * * * /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/reporting/python_scripts/Vertica/get_daily_dpi.py  >> /home/reporting/python_scripts/Vertica/get_daily_dpi.py.log 2>&1
```

I've added `>>` to write error messages to a file.

The script connects to a database, extracts some data, transforms it and loads it into another database. The script runs just fine when I execute it through the command line. From any directory, I can run:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/reporting/python_scripts/Vertica/get_daily_dpi.py
```

However when the crontab tries to run the script it gets the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reporting/python_scripts/Vertica/get_daily_dpi.py", line 8, in <module>
    vc.get_data_from_vertica(cnxn)
  File "/home/reporting/python_scripts/Vertica/vertica_data_connector.py", line 97, in get_data_from_vertica
    row = cur.fetchone()
vertica_db_client.ProgrammingError: No previous call produced results to fetch
```

So it seems like the query returns no results when I run it from crontab but works perfectly fine when I run it from command line.

Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Does the script depend on auth/environment variables maybe?

Comment: @SoZettaSho as far as I know it doesn't. It loads some parameters from a file.  I know it is able to access and read the file.

Comment: The main differences when running a script with cron is that it will run under system, it will run with `/bin/sh/` instead of your preferred shell with your preferred profile, it will have a very minimal set of env variables, etc. Those would be the places to start when trying to rule in/rule out what's the root cause of your problem

Comment: I wish i could say/do more but debugging cron is kind of painful and it's hard for others to help esp. without seeing your code

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working for common issues/resolutions as well

Comment: @SoZettaSho thanks for you suggestions. I have figured it out. Turns out it had nothing to do with Python and Crontab. The table I was accessing was aggregated daily and I was querying it before it finished the aggregation job. So it returned no results. I moved the crontab to be executed a few hours later and that resolved the issue.